# gethostbyaddr() with segmentation fault, why?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I have a c++ program to get the local machine name using `gethostbyaddr()` method, the requirement is to run the program with argument which is an ip address.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    struct hostent * testing_case;
    struct in_addr ipv4addr;
    if (argc != 2) {
        cout<<"Error"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        inet_aton(argv[1],&ipv4addr);
        testing_case = gethostbyaddr(&ipv4addr, sizeof(ipv4addr), AF_INET);
        cout<<"Host Name is: "<<testing_case->h_name<<endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

But when I input the local ip address it returns me a `segmentation fault`, please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Start by checking whether each API call succeeds or fails.

Comment: Check return values of library functions, check that pointers you dereference are not NULL, and if all else fails, use a debugger.

Comment: which value do you pass as `argv[1]` ?

Comment: @mangusta Well I input the local ip address to it.

Comment: @HoweChen how exactly do you input it ? Show the full program call plz

Comment: @mangusta Well I input the 8.8.8.8 and it returns right result, but when I input like 10.4.40.40 it occurs segmentation fault.

Comment: First check if its null, then check the value of "h_errno" do "man gethostbyaddr" for more info.

Comment: `gethostbyaddr()` returns a NULL pointer if an error occurs, like if it cannot resolve the IP address to get DNS info about the host. You are not checking for NULL before trying to read the `hostent` data.  If NULL is returned, use `errno` to find out why. And FYI, the `gethostby...()` functions are deprecated, you really should be using `getnameinfo()` instead in this example.